# Failsafe Against Slips During Audio Programming

Tags: audio, sound-card, music, digital-audio, sound-editing

As described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOLmCQgcQ6E) video, it seems to be very easy to produce dangerous audio volumes (both to speakers and hearing) with Pure Data when even a slight slip or oversight occurs.

The advice given in the video is simply to be very careful, and I have developed a number of habits when working in Pure Data, such as always using external speakers so that (presumably) my machine's internal sound system would not take any damage, keeping my Windows volume control as low as feasible, and adjusting my speaker volume knob up from min volume whenever playing audio.  However, these measures still rely on accurate, human execution.  Having recently read The Design of Everyday Things by Don Norman, I have come to belief that this is a suboptimal design which makes human error very likely to occur.

I am running Pure Data on Windows 7.  Is there a way I can have Windows put a cap on the maximum volume it will allow to play?  To be clear, I do not want a way to turn the Windows volume down more, as I would  then be unable to hear the desired output of Pure Data.  The danger is that the difference between desired volume and potential erroneous volume is many orders of magnitude, so I would like to be able to either put a hard compression ceiling on volume, or simply have the audio muted while it is above a certain volume threshold.  In the former case, it would be nice to also have some signifier to display that the ceiling is being applied.

If this is not possibly via Windows, then is it possible to modifify Pure Data to offer this functionality?

Comment: Have you searched for Windows sound compressors? Many are easily found such as https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Volume-Limiter.shtml (untested). That said, try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for Software Recommendations.

Comment: Hmm, it was not my plan to run an additional program alongside Pure Data.  It seems excessive, but perhaps it is the only solution available.